# The type or namespace name 'Gms' does not exist in the namespace issue

Tags: android, xamarin

I have installed Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base service to fix this. But not working for existing project. if i create a new project and add Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base to it. its working fine.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FFAC.png)

Comment: You can try to choose lower version **Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base**, I install 60.1142.1 version, having no problem.

Comment: My project MonoAndroid version is v10.0 so i can't install lower version.

Comment: I am using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base 71.1610.1

Comment: I install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base version 60.1142.1, have no problem. you can try.